# How to ensure particles will always be aligned in the center

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I'm having trouble figuring out how to ensure particles aligned in a square will always be placed in the middle of the screen, regardless of the size of the square. The square is created with:

```
for(int i=0; i<(int)sqrt(d_MAXPARTICLES); i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<(int)sqrt(d_MAXPARTICLES); j++) {
        Particle particle;
        glm::vec2 d2Pos = glm::vec2(j*0.06, i*0.06) + glm::vec2(-17.0f,-17.0f);
        particle.pos = glm::vec3(d2Pos.x,d2Pos.y,-70);

        particle.life = 1000.0f;
        particle.cameradistance = -1.0f;

        particle.r = d_R;
        particle.g = d_G;
        particle.b = d_B;
        particle.a = d_A;

        particle.size = d_SIZE;
        d_particles_container.push_back(particle);
    }
}
```

the most important part is the `glm::vec2(-17.0f, -17.0f)` which correctly positions the square in the center of the screen. This looks like:

[image]

the problem is that my program supports any number of particles, so only specifying

[image]

now my square is off center, but how can I change `glm::vec2(-17.0f,-17.0f)` to account for different particles?

Answer (score 1):

Do not make position dependent on "i", and "j" indices if you want a fixed position.

```
    glm::vec2 d2Pos = glm::vec2(centerOfScreenX,centerOfScreenY); //much better
```

But how to compute centerOfSCreen? It depends if you are using a 2D or a 3D camera.

- If you use a fixed 2D camera, then center is (Width/2,Height/2).
- If you use a moving 3d camera, you need to launch a ray from the center of the screen and [get any point on the ray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76134/how-do-i-reverse-project-2d-points-into-3d) (so you just use X,Y and then set Z as you wish)

Edit:

Now that the question is clearer here is the answer:

```
    int maxParticles = (int)sqrt(d_MAXPARTICLES);
    factorx = (i-(float)maxParticles/2.0f)/(float)maxParticles;
    factory = (j-(float)maxParticles/2.0f)/(float)maxParticles;
    glm::vec2 particleLocaleDelta = glm::vec2(extentX*factorx,extentY*factory)
    glm::vec2 d2Pos = glm::vec2(centerOfScreenX,centerOfScreenY)
    d2Pos += particleLocaleDelta;
```

where

```
extentX,extentY
```

are the dimensions of the "big square" and factor is the current scale by "i" and "j". The code is not optimized. Just thinked to work (assuming you have a 2D camera with world units corresponding to pixel units).

Comment: well the 'square' isn't really a square, it is a formation of 300,000 particles aligned *like* a square. I can't just set one position for all of the particles as there will just be a tiny dot on the screen. *i* and *j* also denote the distance between each particle, which is quite small.

Comment: Ah ok now your question is clear to me. I'll edit the answer  now